# JavaScript WebStorage - setItem name instead of value

Tags: javascript, session, key-value, session-storage

I have a form with a select field. My select dropdown looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control-edited d-inline-block person-sip insurers" name="options[]" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="1">Option A</option>
    <option value="2">Option B</option>
    <option value="3">Option C</option>
    <option value="4">Option D</option>
    <option value="5">Option E</option>
</select>
```

Now I save the values from the select item to users session with this:

```
let coInsuredPersonsSIP = $('.person-sip').map(function (){ return $(this).val()}).toArray();

if (coInsuredPersonsSIP.length > 0) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('co-insured-persons-sip-hi', JSON.stringify(coInsuredPersonsSIP));

    $('.person-sip').each(function () {
        let sipOriginal = $(this).val();
    });
}
```

This is working good and my key `co-insured-persons-sip-hi` has the value for example `["2","2","5"]`

What I need now:
I do not want to save the values from the dropdown. I want to save the names so that my key/value storage looks like this:

key: `co-insured-persons-sip-hi`
value: `["Option B","Option B","Option E"]`

Is there any chance to achieve this? If so can someone help me on how I have to edit my code?

Comment: Instead of val() use text()

Comment: good point but not working like it should. If I use .text instead of .val it includes all options and not only the selected one. example: key: co-insured-persons-sip-hi value: ["Option A","Option B","Option C","Option D","Option E"] but I only selected Option B

Comment: Filter it out then by using option:selected

Comment: hmm..I do not know exactly how this should work. can you provide me with an example? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: $('.person-sip').find("option:selected").text()

Comment: thanks @John I appreciate your help. I changed my code and added your snippet. Problem now: The .person-sip class exists in multiple select fields. therefore I get all text from every select field in every array. Any solution for that? Only one text per array